# Expand year to months in pandas dataframe and backfill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, fill

I have a dataframe with year and a column of strings, that I would like to expand to include months(1-12) and back fill with the string associated with each year.

This is the starting dataframe:

`Year Data`

```
0   2016     YES
0   2017     NO
0   2018     NO
0   2019     YES
```

I'd like it too look like:

```
Year  Months Climate
0   2016  1   YES
0   2016  2   YES
0   2016  3   YES
...
0   2017  1   NO
0   2017  2   NO
0   2017  3   NO
0   2017  4   NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
# df is the given data in question
df.columns = ['year','flag']

# add a list for months 1-12
df['month'] = [list(range(1, 13)) for _ in range(df.shape[0])]

# convert list into rows
df = df.explode('month').reset_index(drop=True)
```